# How do I dynamically update an object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

Let's say I have an `Action` interface with the given properties.

```
interface Action {
  type: "ADD" | "REMOVE" | "SET"
  property: "users" | "messages" | "video"
  payload: User | Message | Video
}
```

I need to use this interface to manage a state update with the given way.

```
switch (action.type) {
      case "ADD":
        myObj[action.property].push(action.payload);
        break;
      case "REMOVE":
        myObj[action.property] = myObj[action.property].filter(e => e !== action.payload)
        break;
      case "SET":
        myObj[action.property] = action.payload;
        break;
    }
```

But, I get type errors because `action.property` and `action.payload` are not synced (the same), it thinks `action.payload` can be a type of `User` while `action.property` can be a type of a `Message`, which is correct, but I'm trying to figure out how to do this the right way? I've spent countless hours on this, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, we need to make use of `Discriminated unions` for Action type
So that we can instantiate the Generic types uniquely.

In our case `property` is unique in all of the unions, hence we need to instantiate our `Reducer` with it, and based on the passed type, then we are able to capture the return type

Then we can make use of this in the switch statement.
As you can see from the example,

```
interface User {
    name: string
}

interface Video {
    data: string
}

interface Message {
    test: string
}

type Action =  {
  type: "ADD" | "REMOVE" | "SET"
  property: "users"
  payload: User 
} | {
  type: "ADD" | "REMOVE" | "SET"
  property:  "messages" 
  payload: Message 
} | {
  type: "ADD" | "REMOVE" | "SET"
  property:  "video"
  payload:  Video
}
 
declare function Reducer<T extends Action, P extends T["property"]>(action: T, property:P  ): T

let action: Action = { type: 'ADD', property: 'video', payload: {data: '2mb'} }


// Hover over these to see types
let A = Reducer(action, 'video') // A is of type Video now

let myObj: any = {}

switch(action.type) {
        case "ADD":
        myObj[action.property].push(action.payload);
        break;
      case "REMOVE":
        myObj[action.property] = myObj[action.property].filter(e => e !== action.payload)
        break;
      case "SET":
        myObj[action.property] = action.payload;
        break;
}
```

[Code Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHIhwC2EAXMumFKAOa4C%20uuoksiKAasACYQB7HPkK84YOJWq0QDZq3DR4SZAFkI6dHDoo8hZJGpSa9JizABPAA4oAggjDABIZAF4Ceg9YrIARLYARAN9kAB8-ACUAUVUAeS4okPDfAGUogBVfESsoARsoS0pfAFdMKHQsgis4CwAbATheSgwsJjDhAksbIsDg9t9ouISkvzTM7Nz8woJfMk1tDRDsmvrGynV5nWQ28M8un38gkYGY%20MT%20scrkHLzoab8ANz5BK%20q6hqaCHn4BM23%20BC1OBQFAwYogBxOFwRCC8YpIKAAHnSyAgAA9ICBeOhkPZHM4ADTIAAKqIxECxOPSAG1fDcphZfABdAB8AApEPiQJR0kT6XcLORScgAJQ8li1CBgZCcqGUPFQtw4LzdZAAcl6ar5kwFlDVTx%20WuuKw%20lGwYgkeoATCQAEZqxjIeS4AD0LuQAAkBA8sN6sGAABYaFBgISYEPedC4SXS2xKmFwhEcyGE9UGwRqkXIN245DAHECGAq7jPIQgAQAdwlUuQJAssVtACtKHAQBYldh5OgK8AwAgA8muQA6fZZzz6AgIOCYPy9XzkEQT2v1pvU2XOIf8goWJmb0oD9cgTcmxoigDci4ntpBcAA1hel1OZychokF0uCHWG421ymj1vLCZJUv1XQ9Nx1bddxgYBanYNkUFcFlUWQABCVx3DAt5Vl4EVL30a8IDvB8JyfFBUgyec8MIECf0wiDAKVTCT14YilwIoizBYFggA)